# Reexpressing a quantification as a conjunction, disjunction and negation

Tags: predicate-logic

> Suppose that the domain of the propositional function $P(x)$ consists of $-5,-3,-1,1,3,5$. Express $\forall x((x\ne1\rightarrow P(x))$ without using quantifiers, instead using only negations, disjunctions, or conjunctions. Select the choice or choices that correspond to a correct solution.
>
> 1. $P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)\land P(3)\land P(5)$
>
>    $P(-5)\lor P(-3)\lor P(3)\lor P(5)$
>
>    $(x=1)\lor P(1)$
>
>    $\neg P(-1)$
>
>    $\neg P(1)$
>
>    $(x=-5)\land(x=-3)\land(x=-1)\land(x=3)\land(x=1)$

I've managed to work out the following:

When all the elements of in the domain can be listed—say, $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$—it follows that the universal quantification $\forall xP(x)$ is the same as the conjunction $P(x_1)\land P(x_2)\land\cdots\land P(x_n)$. Thus,

$\forall x((x\ne1\rightarrow P(x))
\\ \Rightarrow(-5\ne1\rightarrow P(-5))\land(-3\ne1\rightarrow P(-3))\land\cdots\land(5\ne1\rightarrow P(5))
\\ \Rightarrow(\neg(-5\ne1)\lor P(-5))\land(\neg(-3\ne1)\lor P(-3))\land\cdots\land(\neg(5\ne1)\lor P(5))
\\ \Rightarrow((-5=1)\lor P(-5))\land((-3=1)\lor P(-3))\land\cdots\land((5=1)\lor P(5))
\\ \Rightarrow(\mathbf{F}\lor P(-5))\land(\mathbf{F}\lor P(-1))\land(\mathbf{F}\lor P(-1))\land(\mathbf{T}\lor P(1))\land(\mathbf{F}\lor P(3))\land(\mathbf{F}\lor P(5))
\\ \Rightarrow P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)\land \mathbf{T}\land P(3)\land P(5)
\\ \Rightarrow P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)\land P(3)\land P(5)
$

This shows that choice 1 is correct.

Then choice 2 would have to be incorrect because it allows for any three of $P(-5),P(-3),P(3),P(5)$ to be false, which contradicts choice 1.

I would think choice 3 is correct because $1$ is in the domain.

I think choice 4 is incorrect because it contradicts choice 1.

Choice 5 I'm not sure about. Does choice 1 mean that $P(1)$ is false, or is it left open that it could be true or false?

An then choice 6 I have a similar uncertainty; does the exclusion of $x=5$ mean that $x=5$ is false, or is that left open?

Thank you.

Comment: For 5) and 6) note that the original sentence says nothing about whether $P(1)$ holds.  And it would be useful to rethink 3).

Comment: There is more than one reason 6) is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Starting with 3), if 1 is in the domain, doesn't that make $x=1$ (and therefore $x=1\lor P(1)$) true? EDIT: I think I get it: $x=1$ _can_ be true, but isn't necessarily true (it's false when $x$ is some other value).

Comment: If the orginal sentence is true, then, for example, $P(-5)$ is true.  But from 3) we cannot conclude that $P(-5)$ is true.